# Clear firebase push notifications when reach page

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to clear `push notifications` from (`notification` panel - status bar) when I reach a page in the mobile app. Back-end wise, we are using `firebase` to `push notifications`, while in the app, those are handled with the `firebase_messaging` plugin.

I want to remove those notifications from the `notification` panel when I reach the "notification" page inside the app. Those `push notifications` are not even removed when I open app with icon. Only way to remove those notifications are by clicking on them or manually clear it on the panel.

Comment: You can write code in native for android to remove it from notifications bar using below code 

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem

Comment: Is it work then I'm adding as answer